# Print users name in batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I print the users name from a batch file without the user inputting it?

Like say if my account was called "Bob", it would print "Hi, Bob!"

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do on Windows XP to Windows 7:

```
echo Hi, %USERNAME%!
```

Answer (score 2):

Batch has variables

username is %USERNAME%

so you would write

```
echo Hi, %USERNAME%!
```